# Download your function app files in Azure Functions Consumption plan

Tags: azure-functions

In Azure Functions when you create App Function with 
Hosting Plan: Consumption Plan
Os: Linux
The  Download app content Tab is grayed out.
I cannot use this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#download-your-function-app-files for instructions to download the app code.

Why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies

[image]
As we can see, the only two ways of Linux Consumption Plan function are External package URL and Zip deploy.
That’s why we are not allowed to download contents via portal and API. (Portal editing / Kudu is not supported.

The links below may help you:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#deployment-technology-details
2. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file-or-url
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli-linux

Comment: So, there is no option to download the code from Azure App Function?

Comment: Hi @EladHazan, I think it's better for you to choose app service plan or use windows os.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to finish the tutorial, I can give you the following two suggestions：

**1. to create App functions on linux os：**
follow [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-function-app-linux-app-service-plan#sign-in-to-azure). If you choose App Service Plan, there will be no problem. Why you can't download app content is because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#deployment-technology-availability).

**2. create App functions on windows os:**
even if you choose Consumption Plan, there will also no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can download any Azure function app using the following instructions (you will need appropriate authorization): https://toggen.com.au/it-tips/download-an-azure-function-app-for-development-in-vs-code/